# Mendeley Word plugin pops up with issue on CSL citation schema

Tags: microsoft-word, mendeley

I have a problem with Mendeley Word plugin. Last three days I am getting message "The version of the CSL citation schema in this document is not supported, please try downloading the latest version of Mendeley Desktop from www.mendeley.com." whenever I add another citation in text.

[there is a print-screen of what pops up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGdsr.png)

I browsed the web for answers but it seems the problem is there for years and Mendeley still has not offered official solution. I would be grateful if anyone have any clues what could solve this problem or where can I search for solution I would be sincerely grateful as this message popping up at least twice every time I'm adding citation is really going on my nerves.

If sending my document where the problem occurs can be helpful, I am willing to do so.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if following will work for you, but I'll say what worked for me using a 'new' word document as e.g...this should (hopefully) also work if you do this at start of your (existing) word doc - it won't necessarily eradicate existing errors - for this, it seems you need to find the page/section(s) that are 'buggy', and remove them, as described below.  I've only performed limited testing - no doubt there is a much simpler solution - I have yet to come across it though (but approach below shouldn't take too long)...

**Version:** Mendeley: 1.19.5 (Desktop, Word Plug in); Word: Windows 10

1. Open new word doc (pages: 1)
2. Insert citation using Mendeley plug-in - this should produce the
   error you describe (it also tells me that I don't have the citation
   in my Mendeley library, so I let it add the reference in a new
   folder - after Mendeley checks for duplicates, all it does is add an
   empty folder in Mendeley desktop library, which I simply delete
   later...(pages: still 1)
3. Insert 3 consecutive section breaks after citation in step 2 (pages: 4)
4. On 4th (last page), insert bibliography (this may produce error
   again - it did in my case)... (pages: 4)
5. On 3rd page (before page break on that page), insert another
   reference (I used 'Author_test' - i.e. a test entry/citation I
   'manually added' in Mendeley Desktop) - you may get the error again,
   but hopefully only 1 instance of the annoying pop-up, pertaining to
   first citation - if not, i.e. if you get 2/more Mendeley error
   pop-ups, you may need to start again, following steps in sequence /
   or insert yet another section break (?) - but complete remaining
   steps 5-6 and see if this works first...(pages: 4)
6. Delete pages 1-2, up to (but not including) 'author_test' (pages: 2)

This solved problem for me - I can then add another reference(s) after 'author_test', and remove 'author_test'.... it's not a permanent solution - i.e. it's almost as though an entire page in Word becomes 'buggy' and needs to be deleted for error to buzz off.. otherwise just ignore the error (although it is irritating)....

Note: appears to be similar problem described in Mendeley support under topic 'CSL problem' here: http://mendeley64.rssing.com/chan-15618203/all_p85.html ... however, after clicking on topic, and being presented with a brand new list of topics (that don't show the thread/topic I selected), I (wisely or unwisely) immediately gave up pursuing further...

PS - for steps above, it helps to show paragraph marks (the backwards 'P' icon in Word Doc | Home | Paragraph ribbon....

See following images to clarify:

- [Page 1 (steps 1-3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8n9Ns.png)
- [Page 2 (step 3 contn...)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoS6r.png)
- [Page 3 (step 3 contn and step 5)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KNMm.png)
- [Page 4 (step 4 and step 6)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0B2R.png)
- [Info - insert section break](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOtS1.png)
- [Info - paragraph marks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKXsK.png)
- [Info - add document to library folder (may be unrelated error!)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcDNG.png)

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same pop-up after merging two documents. There were seven of these pop-ups I had to click ok on to make go away.

I solved it by going through and deleting sections one by one (in a 60,000 word document!) to work out where the problematic citations were. The seven problematic citations I found all had '...et al.' in but I think this could be any conflict of schema. Once deleted no more issues.

Mendeley Support's advice was to uninstall and reinstall Mendeley Desktop and the Word Plugin but this wasn't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Further to my original post (Jun 5 at 20:25), I can confirm that this 'solution' also works for existing documents (i.e. not just new word documents) - the three 'section breaks' (step 3) are simply added after each 'buggy' Mendeley citation (bibliography, step 4, can simply be removed afterwards).

These steps also seem to work for instances where the in-text citations default to their field codes (i.e. as though you pressed 'shift+f9' on the citation, which fields a whole scheme blurb between curly brackets)...

J

Answer (score 0):

I just also came across this issue, but luckily, was able to fix it.

In my case, the problem stemmed from having a reference within a Word math equation.

After removing the citation from the math equation by making the reference normal text the error message stopped and Word was operating fine again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I just also came across this issue, but luckily, was able to fix it.

In my case, the problem stemmed from having a reference within a Word math equation.

After removing the citation from the math equation by making the reference normal text the error message stopped and Word was operating fine again.

Hope this helps.